# view page is not rendering in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

i'm new in spring and i'm trying to do is that using spring boot i want to render jsp or html page.
i created a project where i add all of the dependencies and even i add spring mvc view page configuration in application.properties.

here is my project link [Project Link](https://github.com/SONU74268/webspring).

i googled but i find answer is that i need to update my pom.xml to war and even i updated this but still don't get response.

i'm adding pom.xml and controller class

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>webspring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>webspring</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To compile JSP files -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**controller class**

@Controller
public class DemoController {

```
@RequestMapping("/res")
public String sendRes() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/demo")
@ResponseBody
public String setDemo() {
    return "This is responce";
}
```

}

- response body work properly.

where am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `application.properties` you have `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/`, whereas package has name `views`

Comment: @GeorgyLvov hello, thank you it helps. if you don't mind can i ask one more thing.